# Is it possible to map two relationships with a single column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working with JPA on a legacy database. The actual semantics are that `foo` owns the relationship, and that it really only has a single `bar`, which would require an `@ManyToOne` annotation.

```
foo     (id, bar_id)
foo_bar (foo_id, bar_id)
bar     (id)
```

Anything ending in `_id` is a foreign key. Also, the columns in `foo_bar` make up a primary key.

In an ideal world, I would just trash the `foo_bar` table, but there are other applications that use the same database, which might break if it's left out. How would I map this relationship completely?

If not, what would be a good way to keep the integrity of this messy relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the `foo.bar_id` column to a `ManyToOne` relationship. Map the join table to `ManyToMany` relationship. Don't provide accessors to the collection of `bars` in `Foo`. Make the `setBar()` clear the collection of bars and add the new one to it.

This way, the ManyToMany association is completely encapsulated inside to ManyToOne association handling.

```
public class Foo {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
    private Bar bar;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(...)
    private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<Bar>();

    // no getter, setter or any other method for the bars collection

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.bars.clear();
        if (bar != null) {
            this.bars.add(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jpa to map above relationship. no worries.